# How to return IDs within a wx.Rect in Wxpython PseudoDC

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I am making a "Box Select" tool for a program I am developing in Wxpython. I am using the *PseudoDC* class for the drawing.

The user should able to draw a box to select drawn node objects on the nodegraph by their ID, but I am unable to figure out a good way to get the IDs that are within the Box selection.

So far, I have come up with the following:

```
    def OnLeftUp(self, event):
            ...
            # This is in the mouse event method which calls the *BoxSelectHitTest* method below.
            self._selectednodes = self.BoxSelectHitTest(
                wx.Point(self._bboxRect[2]/2, 
                    self._bboxRect[3]/2)
                )
            ...
```

```
    def BoxSelectHitTest(self, pt):
        # self._bboxRect is the wx.Rect of the Box Select
        average = (self._bboxRect[3] + self._bboxRect[2])/2
        idxs = self._pdc.FindObjects(pt[0], pt[1], int(average))

        hits = [
            idx 
            for idx in idxs
            if idx in self._nodes
        ]
        # Return the node objects from the IDs
        if hits != []:
            nodes = []
            for Id in hits:
                nodes.append(self._nodes[Id])
            return nodes

        else:
            return []
```

This is obviously not a true box select. It is more like a bad version of a circle select. (The radius by the average is just my attempt at making it "work".)

I couldn't find *a method in PseudoDC that would return the IDs of objects within a given wx.Rect*. **Is there a method that does this or how should this be implemented correctly?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by looking through the documentation on wx.Rect, so I thought I would post it here.

Using `wx.Rect.Intersects` it checks if the bboxrect intersects with each node's rect and returns them:

```
    def BoxSelectHitTest(self, bboxrect):
        nodehits = []
        for node in self._nodes.values():
            if bboxrect.Intersects(node.GetRect()) == True:
                nodehits.append(node)

        if nodehits != []:
            return nodehits

        else:
            # Make sure we deselect everything
            for node in self._selectednodes:
                node.SetSelected(False)
                node.Draw(self._pdc)
            self._selectednodes = []
            return []
```